# Replacing ssh-agent for gpg-agent

Tags: 18.04, ssh, gnupg

I was trying to use `gpg-agent` as a "drop-in replacement" of `ssh-agent`.

My understanding was that I needed to:

- add `enable-ssh-support` to ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
- comment `use-ssh-agent` from `/etc/X11/Xsession.options`

But I rebooted the system and it doesn't seem as if it was working:

```
$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
```

The gpg works as expected --if I manually export the correct `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, then everything works correctly.

Am I missing some step? I know I could workaround a lot of things to force it, but I was trying to find the minimal configuration required.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is inconsistent here. `man Xsession.option` says first:

> Options are enabled by simply placing them in the file; they are disabled by
>   prefixing the option name with ‘no-’.

But near the end:

> All of the above options are enabled by default.

So instead of commenting out `use-ssh-agent` replace it with `no-use-ssh-agent`.

Comment: I did what you said and experienced no difference. After your comment I introduced a debugging monkeypatch variable inside `Xsession.d/90x11-common_ssh-agent`, which seems to be responsible of ssh-agent stuff. But I can assure that the inside of the conditional is **not** being executed. "Somebody else" is initializing ssh-agent stuff, but I don't know who it may be.

Comment: Hmm.. I have no other suggestions. I was just trying to achieve the same thing the other day, and your question actually helped me to do it, just with this one change.

Just for reference: another way to check whether the ssh-agent was started from Xsession is check output of ps: on my system before disabling it I had an entry with startplasma-x11 getting ssh-agent as argument. The ssh-agent argument disappeared after adding the "no-"

Comment: I am pretty sure that if you are running Gnome the  GNOME Keyring agent will interfere with GnuPG as well and there is no trivial way to deactivate it. Check `SSH_AGENT_PID` to pinpoint who's the culprit there.